# Confused about how to structure an Electron app

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm just starting out with Electron and am a little confused about how to structure the project.

With basic web pages you would just obviously use HTML pages containing links to your JS and CSS

With MERN apps you would have have your front end separated from your routes and then your back end separate to that using the 'require' function to put everything together.

I've built a simple practice app that creates a to-do list. At the moment it has the following files:

package.json main.js mainWindow.html addWindow.html

Now I've started to add connections to the database I'm not sure where to put it. At the moment, when an item is added from the addWindow.html, and the IPC Renderer sends the parameters to main.js, I added code in the function there to also call the database insert function:

```
ipcMain.on('item:add', function(e, inputItems){
    console.log("shop item" + inputItems)
    dbInsert(inputItems)
    mainWindow.webContents.send('item:add', inputItems)
})
```

I then have my dbInsert() function in main.js also

```
function dbInsert(inputItem){
    let db = new sqlite3.Database('sldb.db', (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
        }
        console.log('Connected to the sqlite database.');
      });
    db.run(`INSERT INTO items (itemName, itemCat) VALUES(?, ?)`, inputItem.shopItem,     inputItem.shopItemCat), function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err.message);
        }
      };
}
```

Eventually though my main.js will be a huge mess. What is the correct way to structure things in Electron? How should I separate out these different functions and how should I connect them together? Do I simple 'include' JS files in the main.js file or is there a 'require' way of doing things?

Comment: What error message?

Comment: Just understand wrong, sorry

Comment: you could use `require` to connect them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out [`secure-electron-template`](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template), I notice you refer to IPC messaging, this template has it built in as well as many comments and good documentation.

What I recommend to your question of saving to the database, is creating a separate module to handle this, and simply set up bindings in your main.js file like I do in this line: https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template/blob/master/app/electron/main.js#L60.

The topic is quite large and detailed, but I think you can find inspiration by looking at this file as well: https://github.com/reZach/i18next-electron-fs-backend/blob/master/src/index.js